# Adding generic method throws type error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and __ does not exist in type __

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

My goal is that foo accepts any object which extends an `Obs<T>`. However I get the following error.

```
Argument of type '{ reset: () => number; x: number; set: (x: number) => number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Obs<unknown>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'reset' does not exist in type 'Obs<unknown>'
```

**Snippet A**

```
{
  // add a generic method 
  type Obs<T> = { x: T; set: (x: T) => T }
  function createObs<T>(x: T): Obs<T> {
    return { x, set: (val: T) => val }
  }
  function foo<O extends Obs<T>, T>(a: O) {}
  const a = createObs(1)
  foo({ ...a, reset: () => 1 }) // ❌ now throws the error
}
```

Interestingly if I remove the `set` method the types work as expected like so.

**Snippet B**

```
{
  type Obs<T> = { x: T }
  function createObs<T>(x: T): Obs<T> {
    return { x }
  }
  function foo<O extends Obs<T>, T>(a: O) {}
  const a = createObs(1)
  foo({ ...a, reset: () => 1 }) // ✅
}
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/N4KABGAuCeAOCmYDyAjAzgHgCoD4wF4xgwAPALjCwG4w15IKAKcygSgLyzAF9wwAzAK4A7AMaQAlgHthYUQCd4AQ0jxUmXMwpZWFddjygIERZEHzZxEgBpa9JgDclAG23t8eJ8559eEIWKSMgJSUhhIYPAkqsIAJmjI6Aa2mkp67MB+cjJokGBKBHKKKmrojACMrHz8oYzEAHSNSraKdAxgjO545TxVvCBGUHCI+riFVto+-iLi0rIKyqqjOFpsekljgyb05pakUwcBs8E1YRFRMfGJGjgpK2nIGVmiOXkFhAsl6hVV-rUNTRa8DaTC6YB63D6ICAA)

How do I make Snippet A work with the generic `set` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems seems to be associated with the fact that you are not defining what will be the default value of `T` in the `foo` function.

If you `infer` T default type by whatever was passed into `Obs`, typescript will have just enough information to use the type you passed into the `createObs` function previously.

```
{
  type Obs<T> = { x: T; set: (x: T) => T };
  function createObs<T>(x: T): Obs<T> {
    return { x, set: (val: T) => val };
  }
  function foo<O extends Obs<T>, T = O extends Obs<infer R> ? R : never>(
    a: O
  ) {}
  const a = createObs(1);
  foo({ ...a, reset: () => 1 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add extra generic parameter:

```
// U is extra generic parameter
type Obs<T> = { x: T; set: <U extends T>(x: U) => T }

function createObs<T>(x: T): Obs<T> {
  return { x, set: (val: T) => val }
}
function foo<O extends Obs<T>, T>(a: O) { }
const a = createObs(1)
a.set(2) // ok
foo({ ...a, reset: () => 1 })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA8gIwM4B4AqA%20GBeGBvGADwC4Y0BuGJKEUlAVRikJCgDsATJMjAChJj0AlDixoYAX2DAAZgFc2AYxABLAPZsYigE5QAhq0SpM-UmiGkj6LHmAwYukHO2aChADRUapXgDc9ADZmIthY-gGSwFLySqoaMDJqaihwTCzsXPDI1p4mepYiBFKKGkggMHo4WroGUEa8AIxCwHoAdNQgvABMIgD0vTBqANaySbwErZN6nrodPiFYDZLN0kA)

`T` is covariant in `type Obs<T> = { x: T }`.
Consider this example:

```js
type Obs<T> = { x: T }

let foo: Obs<number> = { x: 0 }

let bar: Obs<42> = { x: 42 }

foo = bar
```

`bat` is assignable to `foo`.

But if you add a `set` method, like here:

```js
type Obs<T> = { x: T, set: (x: T) => T }
```

`T` becomes invariant.

```js
type Obs<T> = { x: T, set: (x: T) => T }

let foo: Obs<number> = { x: 0, set: (val) => val }

let bar: Obs<42> = { x: 42, set: (val) => val }

foo = bar // error
bar = foo // error
```

`bar` is no more assignable to `foo`.

Hence, if you want to make it work, you need to make argument of `set` a subtype of `T`.

To be honest, I'm not sure about `T becomes invariant`. So, if you have any arguments about that I am open to criticism.

P.S. more about *-variance you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc)